# CSS - Target an element and its sibling upon hover

Tags: html, css

Quick question for you guys. I know how to use a selector to target an element on hover, and also how to target an elements sibling. Is there a way to combine these?

Dont worry about why I want to do it, long story short, they work better not targeting the parent in this situation.

A good live example of this is the following fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrHfr/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="puppy">
    <div class="ducky">
        Boom
    </div>
    <div class="kitty">
        awww, im dead
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.puppy {width:400px;}

.ducky {position:absolute; left:-120px; width:200px; background-color:blue; margin-left:50%;}

.kitty {position:absolute; left:-60px; width:300px; background-color:red; margin-left:50%;}

.kitty:hover ~ .ducky {color:white;}
```

In the example above, hovering over kitty should change the color of the words in both kitty and ducky to white (if it worked how I desired.)

I can find another way to do this, but ti seems like it would be more efficient to do it this way if I can get it to work. No Js or jQuery here please. Not needed to accomplish this.

Comment: Your CSS targets `.dog`, I presume it should be `.ducky`.  Anyway you can't target a sibling element that's comes before the element you are hovering.  In this case, as you want to change the color in both siblings, why not when you hover on the parent?

Comment: yes. I meant to say ducky. I will update. You cant do it? eh...bummer. Theres a responsive design set up on my employers site and there is a button that grows and shrinks in size. There is also a css triangle I placed over the button. I have a nice centering code in place that affects the parent so its width is larger than I wanted. The hover effect on the parent activates too early(proximity-wise) if on parent.

Comment: So are you saying that you'd want to control the hover effect of the CSS triangle as well?  Can you not place that element after the `.kitty` element?  Then the sibling selector will work.  Or, have you considered using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to create the triangle?

Comment: Yeah. Its not giving a consistent result though. I needed to push the triangle over from the the middle, not from the sides which is the problem. Oh wait. I guess I could just use margin-left:50%; then apply a left:(certain amount of px);

You helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: It's normally the other way round - `left: 50%`, `margin-left: -XXpx`.  Feel free to come back if you get stuck again!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Hover on element doesn't apply style to another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726800/css-hover-on-element-doesnt-apply-style-to-another-one)

Answer (score 1):

```
.puppy {width:400px;}

.ducky {position:absolute; left:-120px; width:200px; background-color:blue; margin-left:50%;}

.kitty {position:absolute; left:-60px; width:300px; background-color:red; margin-left:50%;}

.kitty:hover ~ .dog {color:white;}
```

It looks like David beat me to the punch. Here is a quick example though that I threw together.

http://jsfiddle.net/emersive/58MwP/2/

Comment: Yeah. Starting to think Im gonna be using jQuery. No problem just wanted to try and be efficient. Thanks.

Comment: I think the other thing that might be happening here is the order. For  some reason it seems like the order matters. For example, you can see in my example that if you swap the order of .sibling1 and .sibling2 in the css selector. I think it will only recognize subsequent siblings not siblings that fall before it in the DOM. jQuery is probably not a bad way to do it. If all you are going to use it for that, I might just use vanilla javascript, jQuery might be overkill.

Comment: Very valid point. Good observation. Thanks for this. It really helps.