# CSS - Hover on element doesn't apply style to another one

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a problem with applying style to a div when another div is hovered. Here is my scenario:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="logged"></div>
    <div class="nav_child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.logged:hover .nav_child {
    display: initial;
}
#nav .nav_child {
    display: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried `.logged:hover > .nav_child` and `.logged:hover + .nav_child` and still nothing. It only works with `#nav:hover .nav_child` but I need to show it when `.logged` is hovered, not when `#nav` is hovered.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not do it using javascript or jquery?

Comment: try `.nav_child{ display: none; }` on nav_child directly without descendant selector from #nav. http://jsfiddle.net/aw4ejhys/

Comment: Solved, see my answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @gp. it's really strange cause I tried that on my site and it doesn't work, but no problems on jsfiddle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved with the **Adjacent sibling combinator**. I declare and call 'logged' as id and add + between .logged:hover and .nav_child it works.

*Reference: Adjacent sibling combinator: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors*

Old code: http://jsfiddle.net/8rdh7m2j/

Working code:

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="logged" id="logged">Hello</div>
<div class="nav_child">Puff</div>
</div>
#logged:hover + .nav_child {
display: initial;
}

#nav .nav_child {
display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hwh3o8u0/1/

Comment: That's because you're using the Adjacent sibling combinator: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Even just remove the #nav from child and +

```
.logged:hover+.nav_child {
    display:initial;
}
 .nav_child {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dz22m10y/

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with the `.logged:hover + .nav_child` approach. The reason it didn't work is that `#nav .nav_child` has higher specificity (because it includes an ID), and therefore takes precedence over the preceding rule.

Yes, you could solve that by moving to an ID for `logged`, as you did in your self-answer, but instead of doing that, you could raise specificity of the hovering rule by adding in the ID you've already got there too:

```
#nav .logged:hover + nav_child {
```

By the way, such problems can nearly always be tracked down using the style inspector in your browser's dev panel. In this case, you would see both rules, and you would see that the second was overriding the first. That would easily lead you to the conclusion that it is a specificity problem. Most style inspectors will give you the ability to "emulate" a hovering state.

For more information on specificity, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. In your case, your original first rule had a specificity of 20 (two classes), and the second one 101 (one ID and one class).

Comment: @gp Can you give an example of display working when color does not?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a good resource that covers this topic http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/a3y52/
<div id="nav">
    <div id="one" class="logged"></div>
    <div id="two" class="nav_child"></div>
</div>
#one:hover ~ two,
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```